# IndexError: string index out of range Exception in Tkinter callback

Tags: python, tkinter

string index is correct but it showing out of range

```
  def get_cursor(self,event=""):
                curser_focus=self.student_table.focus()
                content=self.student_table.item(curser_focus)
                data=content["values"]
        
                self.var_dep.set(data[0]),
                self.var_course.set(data[1]),
                self.var_year.set(data[2]),
                self.var_semester.set(data[3]),
                self.var_std_id.set(data[4]),
                self.var_std_name.set(data[5]),``
                self.var_div.set(data[6]),
                self.var_roll.set(data[7]),
                self.var_gender.set(data[8]),
                self.var_dob.set(data[9]),
                self.var_email.set(data[10]),
                self.var_phone.set(data[11]),
                self.var_address.set(data[12]),
                self.var_blood_group.set(data[13]),
                self.var_redio1.set(data[14])
```

output:

```
   self.var_dep.set(data[0]),
                     ~~~~^^^
IndexError: string index out of range
```

while creating it does not show any error but now it showing
what should i do?

Comment: In `data=content["values"]`, `content["values"]` must not be an iterable. Maybe it's empty or None

Comment: When will the function be executed?  You can simply print out the value of `data` to see whether it is what you expect.